# ¿Por que se duplican los datos de esta función .click? javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

cuando realizo un fetch desde aquí:

```
function prueba(){
    var buscar1 = $('#id_buscar').val().toString();

    // console.log(buscar1);
    if(!buscar1.isEmpty()){
        let url="http://mi_ip_va_aqui/api/cl/"+buscar1
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => testingvalues(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }
    else{
        hide_table()
        $("#error_msg").html("<br><br>Debe ingresar un número de transacción.");
    }
}
```

entra en esta función:

```
function testingvalues(data){
    if (data == "No existe cliente."){
        hide_table();
        $("#error_msg").html("<br><br>No Existe el cliente ingresado.");
    }
    else{
        showproducts(data);
        function showproducts(){
            $('#button_test').click(function(){
                console.log("--------------------------");
                console.log("Datos cliente");
                console.log("rut: "+data.rut);
                console.log("nombre: "+data.nombre_cl);
                console.log("dirección: "+data.direccion);
                console.log("--------------------------");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

y muestra por consola los valores correspondientes, pero cuando vuelvo a realizar el fetch con otro valor, me trae los datos anteriores más el actual y no se porque sucede eso.

Este es el primer fetch
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando hago el segundo fetch con un valor diferente, sucede esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No debería traerme los datos del anterior más los datos del nuevo, solo debería obtener el último que busque, muchas gracias

Cambios sugeridos:

```
function testingvalues(data){
    if (data == "No existe cliente."){
        hide_table();
        $("#error_msg").html("<br><br>No Existe el cliente ingresado.");
    }
    else{
        showproducts(data);
    }
}
function showproducts(data){
    $('#button_test').click(function(){
        console.log("--------------------------");
        console.log("Datos cliente");
        console.log("rut: "+data.rut);
        console.log("nombre: "+data.nombre_cl);
        console.log("dirección: "+data.direccion);
        console.log("--------------------------");
    });
}
```

button_test es claramente un botón, realize esto y no cambio nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siento que lo que está pasando es que cada vez qué haces una consulta, agregas una nueva función onClick al botón. Es decir cada vez que defines el onClick en el botón, se está agregando una nueva función a ejecutar. Y por lo tanto terminas con dos funciones que se ejecutan con el mismo botón.

¿Podrías intentar limpiar las funciones del botón antes de agregar otra función?

`$('#buttonTest').off('click');` justo antes de la línea en la que defines la función del click para el botón.

Comment: en cual de los 2?

Comment: gracias jacobo, habrá alguna forma de agregar amigos en stackoverflow xd?

Comment: No lo creo. Pero si entras a mi perfil de StackOverflow está mi twitter. Puedes mandarme una petición de seguimiento si gustas.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque has definido la función showproducts() dentro de testingvalues() y a cada llamada a testingvalues() se redeclara showproducts(). Declárala fuera de la función testingvalues().

Comment: aun sigue haciendo lo mismo, actualizaré el código para que veas